# ORA-07455: estimated execution time (386781721 secs), exceeds limit (86400 secs)

Tags: sql, oracle

I am trying to run one query while its fail due to "ORA-07455: estimated execution time (386781721 secs), exceeds limit (86400 secs)"

Could you any one give me some suggestion to resolve this issue? This is query I tried:

```
SELECT DISTINCT
    batch.id,
    UPPER(TRIM(NVL(t2.user_login, DECODE( INSTR(CAST(T.COLUMN_VALUE.EXTRACT('//text()') AS VARCHAR2(200)),'@',1,1),0,CAST(T.COLUMN_VALUE.EXTRACT('//text()') AS VARCHAR2(200)),
    SUBSTR(CAST(T.COLUMN_VALUE.EXTRACT('//text()') AS VARCHAR2(200)),1, (INSTR(CAST(T.COLUMN_VALUE.EXTRACT('//text()') AS VARCHAR2(200)),'@',1,1)-1)))))) AS USER_LOGIN,
    UPPER(CAST(t.COLUMN_VALUE.EXTRACT('//text()') AS VARCHAR2(200))) AS EMAIL_ADDRESS ,
    t1.BATCH_ID,
    t1.CREATED_BY
FROM
    message t1,
     TABLE( xmlsequence( XMLTYPE( '<x><x>'  || REPLACE(t1.RECIPIENTS, ',', '</x><x>')  || '</x></x>' ).EXTRACT('//x/*'))) t, --CHR(13)  ||CHR(10)
    BATCH,
  (
    SELECT DISTINCT
        user_login,
        sender
    FROM
        MESSAGE, BATCH
where BATCH.ID = MESSAGE.ID and BATCH.ID=1
  )
  t2
WHERE
    BATCH.BATCH_ID                                          = t1.BATCH_ID
    AND CAST(t.COLUMN_VALUE.EXTRACT('//text()') AS VARCHAR2(200)) = t2.sender(+) 
and t1.id=1
    ORDER BY   batch.id,  USER_LOGIN
```

this is query am trying to execute.

Comment: _386781721 secs_ is a very long time. Unless you actually expect your query to run over the next 373 years, i would consider what your query is actually doing. Seems like you have yourself stuck in a loop somewhere

Comment: You're user has a reousource limit imposed. Oracle thinks you're going to exceeded with this query and therefore blocks it. You can increase/remove the limit, which doesn't help if it really takes 373 years. Maybe statistics are invalid and Oracle execution time estimate is wrong. Then you should recompute the statistics. Or you should rewrite your query to be more efficient.

Comment: What's are you trying to achieve anyway? What is all this XML stuff for? Just to split a comma separated string?

Comment: Looks like you created a cartesian product. There are 4 tables in your query and only 2 joins in your where clause.

Comment: Good point. And a good reason to get rid of old habits: [Bad habits to kick : using old-style JOINs](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/08/bad-habits-to-kick-using-old-style-joins)